# What value should I use for the SQLSVCACCOUNT parameter when installing SQL Server Express 2008 R2 from the command line with SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe?

Tags: windows, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using the following command to install SQL Server Express 2008 R2 on various operating systems(Windows XP. Server 2003, Server 2008, Server 2008 R2, and 7), but I'm unsure what account to use (and why) for the SQLSVCACCOUNT parameter.  This SQL Server install will be part of a web application running on the same computer, and all of it will be installed using an NSIS script.

```
SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe /Q /ACTION=Install /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ROLE=AllFeatures_WithDefaults /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /SecurityMode=SQL /SAPWD="xxxxxxx"
```

Will "NT Authority\Network Service" work for all of the operating systems on my list?  Or maybe I should be using a different account altogether?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Network service is the way to go in all operating systems, Local system grants higher privileges than you're likely to need.

Answer (score 2):

The above is true,  but if you are installing to a Small Business Server or a Server acting as a Domain Controller you may get this error:

```
Exit code (Decimal):           -2068578304
Exit facility code:            1204
Exit error code:               0
Exit message:                  Network Service or Local Service account is not permitted for the SQL Server service on a domain controller. Specify a different account.
```

You will need to specify specific accounts under these circumstances.